# TortoiseGit: Context menu not showing git sync option

Tags: tortoisegit

Yesterday i find out that the sync option and the pull otion have disapeared from my TortoiseGit context menu. I tried checking them in the context menu but they where already checked. I also tried to uninstall TortoiseGit and install it again but it doesn't fix the problem.
Does anybody know what the problem could be?

Comment: Where are the options checked?

Comment: Setting -> General -> Context Menu     and         Setting -> General -> Context Menu 2

Answer (score 0):

Please read title for "Context menu 2". It states "Hide the selected items on the context menu".

That is the reason why those options are hidden by default.

Cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-look-feel and https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-look-feel-extended

Comment: @reverso Does this answer your question? if yes please consider to accept it (that's the way to say thank you on SO) or add a comment.